# Unordered list display inline jumps to new line when resized

Tags: html, css

I want to list a number of categories that an item is contained in. Each category is displayed in a bootstrap badge. It should look something like this:

```
Also In: sport, health & fitness, lifestyle, cardio, biomechanics, pottery
```

The categories are displayed using an unordered list, and each element are displayed inline.

The problem arises when the resizing the window, the "categories-list-div" pops down to a new line below the 'Also In:' text. The preferred behavior would be the div to stay in line, and the elements to wrap around to look something like this:

```
 Also in: sport, health & fitness, lifestyle, cardio, biomechanics,
          pottery
```

Instead it looks like this:

```
Also in:
sport, health & fitness, lifestyle, cardio, biomechanics, pottery
```

Any ideas how I can get it working? I've created a plnkr to show you exactly what is happening: http://plnkr.co/edit/42ZLWgfISBfMWXvoSAhR

The html looks like this:

```
<div class="categories-div">
  Also In:
  <div class="categories-list-div">
    <ul class="category-list">
      <li class="category-list-item">
        <span class="badge badge-category">sport</span>
      </li>
      <li class="category-list-item">
        <span class="badge badge-category">fitness</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for the div, ul, and li elements are:

```
.categories-list-div {
    display:inline-block;
}
.category-list {
    margin-left:0px;
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:0;
}
.category-list-item {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
<div style="float:left; width: 50px;">Also in:</div>
<div class="categories-div" style="float:left; width: calc(100% - 50px);">
    <div class="categories-list-div">
    <ul class="category-list">
      <li class="category-list-item">
        <span class="badge badge-category">sport</span>
      </li>
...
```

I edited the Plunker to be as you see above.

Here is my changed version: http://plnkr.co/edit/5Wk1jDOgKUg7f0uEj4wM?p=preview

Comment: That does keep the line from jumping, but the elements that are put on the new line go directly under the 'Also in:' text, instead of under the first category name...

Comment: Whoops I missed that subtlety, Iv'e edited my response to achieve that.